How can I list all users from my Cognito Pool?
I'm making a new fullstack app using aws amplify gen2. I've just started working, and a critical functionality of my app is listing and managing current users in the cognito pool, however, the amplify docs don't have a guide on this but only the aws Cognito docs do. I tried to copy and paste some code into my app.tsx to list all users but I keep getting an error that my Region is missing. Below I have the code snippets pertaining my issue. How can I list and manage all users?
import { CognitoIdentityProviderClient, ListUsersCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";

/... Other code .../

const listUsers = () => {
    const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({});
  
    const command = new ListUsersCommand({
      UserPoolId: "My User Pool Id",
    });
  
     console.log(client.send(command));
 };

/... Other code .../

<button onClick={listUsers()}>Click</button>

/... Other code .../

I have tried to look for posts about this issue and other aws docs but nothing has helped.

You need to write a custom lambda function, where you have to use Cognito SDK to get the users. Connect that Lambda function with your CustomQuery as a dataSource to get the data.

I think I answered my own question with this link -> https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/grant-access-to-auth-resources/
But one other question... based on the following code snippet, how could I make it such that a specific email gets specific privileges?
/**
 * Define and configure your auth resource
 * @see https://docs.amplify.aws/gen2/build-a-backend/auth
 */
export const auth = defineAuth({
  loginWith: {
    email: true,
  },
});

Thanks!

i.e. I would like to have an admin account and the ability to add users from inside of the app
Thanks!
